# Use COUNT() for multiple columns over several years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sql-server-2012

I have a query that displays a count of wells for the current year.  I'd like to show the count/year for the past 5 years.  How could I do this in a single query?

For the current year, I am using `YEAR(GETDATE())`.  For the past five years, I was thinking I could use: `YEAR(GETDATE())-1`, `YEAR(GETDATE())-2`, `YEAR(GETDATE())-23`, etc.  I also thought a `CASE WHEN` clause could work but wasn't sure how to use it under the `SELECT` statement.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(w.WellType, 'Totals') AS 'WellTypes',
    COUNT(DISTINCT(w.WellID)) AS '2021'
FROM Well w
    LEFT JOIN Construct c ON c.WellKey = w.PKey
    LEFT JOIN ConstructDate cd ON c.PKey = cd.ConstructKey
WHERE
    YEAR(cd.EventDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND cd.Event = 'LATERALSTATUS'
    AND cd.Comment = 'PA'
GROUP BY ROLLUP(w.WellType)
ORDER BY
    CASE w.WellType
        WHEN 'OW' THEN 1
        WHEN 'GW' THEN 2
        WHEN 'D' THEN 3
        WHEN 'OWI' THEN 4
        WHEN 'WI' THEN 5
    END DESC
```

Here are my current results:

| WellTypes | 2021 |
| --- | --- |
| WI | 10 |
| OWI | 1 |
| D | 21 |
| GW | 40 |
| OW | 72 |
| Totals | 144 |

This is what I'd like to get:

| WellTypes | 2021 | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 | 2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WI | 10 | 6 | 0 | 5 | 2 |
| OWI | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 5 |
| D | 21 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| GW | 40 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 7 |
| OW | 72 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Totals | 144 | 15 | 7 | 14 | 18 |

I'm working on getting this in db-fiddle but I've never used it before.  I know this is super long but for now, here's the plain data in a table.  The "EventDate", "Comment", and "Event" columns are from a table called, "ConstructDate".  The "WellType" column is from a table called, "Well".

| EventDate | WellType | Comment | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2017 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/3/2017 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/4/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/4/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/5/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/5/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/5/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/5/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/5/2017 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/1/2018 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2018 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2019 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/1/2020 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 1/2/2020 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | WI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | OWI | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | D | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/16/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/18/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | GW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/17/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/18/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/18/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/18/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/19/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/19/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/19/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/19/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/19/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/20/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/21/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/22/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/22/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/23/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/23/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/23/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/23/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/23/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/23/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |
| 8/24/2021 | OW | PA | LATERALSTATUS |

Comment: Can you include sample data for your expected results - ideally in a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or as text in your question.

Comment: @Stu the expected data is made up.  Let me see if I can put something together.  It's basically two columns of data: one showing the date and the other showing the well types.

Comment: Side points: `WHERE YEAR(cd.EventDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())` is inefficient because of the function over the column (can't use indexes), better to use `WHERE cd.EventDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) -4, 1, 1)`. Your left joins become inner joins due to the `WHERE` clauses. Instead of `COALESCE(w.WellType, 'Totals')` it's better to use `CASE WHEN GROUPING(w.WellType) = 0 THEN w.WellType ELSE 'Totals' END`. You shouldn't use `''` single quotes to delimit column names, use `[]` instead

Comment: @Charlieface Why use `CASE WHEN GROUPING(w.WellType) = 0 THEN w.WellType ELSE 'Totals' END` over `COALESCE(w.WellType, 'Totals')`?

Comment: Mainly because if `WellType` can also be null then there will be two null rows, one for the nul and one for the total. It also makes the intent clearer

Comment: @Charlieface Ok. In this case, there won't be any WellTypes equalling NULL, every well has a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky when you need different constraints to aggregate what you want. I wouldn't use count, I would sum the instances instead with CASE statements. Here is an example you can run in your session on SQL Server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP(
    WellType            NVARCHAR(10)
    ,EventDate          DATE
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP (WellType, EventDate)
VALUES ('OW','2021-11-03')
    ,('GW','2020-11-03')
    ,('D','2019-11-03')
    ,('OWI','2018-11-03')
    ,('WI','2017-11-03')
    ,('WI','2021-11-03')
    ,('D','2020-11-03')
    ,('D','2019-11-03')
    ,('GW','2018-11-03')
    ,('OW','2017-11-03')
    ,('OW','2021-11-03')
    ,('GW','2020-11-03')
    ,('D','2019-11-03')
    ,('OWI','2018-11-03')
    ,('WI','2017-11-03')
    ,('WI','2021-11-03')
    ,('D','2020-11-03')
    ,('D','2019-11-03')
    ,('GW','2018-11-03')
    ,('OW','2017-11-03')

SELECT 
    WellType
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(EventDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [THIS YEAR]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(EventDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [LAST YEAR]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(EventDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [2 YEARS AGO]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(EventDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-3,GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [3 YEARS AGO]
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY WellType
```

I also use the GETDATE() function to establish what year to sum. This should do what you want.

OUTPUT BEFORE AND AFTER SELECT STATEMENT:
[image]

Comment: This works except I had to replace `Welltype` under `SELECT` with `COALESCE(w.WellType, 'Totals') AS 'WellTypes'` to get my `Totals` row to work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your own query without the tables involved and relevant data, however there are a number of ways of pivoting the data you require into columns.

One such method is to use a `conditional case expression`, another is to use `window analytic functions`:

```
select distinct welltype, 
    Count(case when Year(Eventdate)=Year(GetDate())-0 then 1 end) over(partition by welltype ) [2021],
    Count(case when Year(Eventdate)=Year(GetDate())-1 then 1 end) over(partition by welltype ) [2020],
    Count(case when Year(Eventdate)=Year(GetDate())-2 then 1 end) over(partition by welltype ) [2019],
    Count(case when Year(Eventdate)=Year(GetDate())-3 then 1 end) over(partition by welltype ) [2018],
    Count(case when Year(Eventdate)=Year(GetDate())-4 then 1 end) over(partition by welltype ) [2017]
from t
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cfd2ee882c8d5f12ce038119a08b0ef1)

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting db-fiddle put together in a reasonable amount of time.  For now, I added a table with all of the sample data.  Does that help at all?  Let me know if you need me to clarify anything about the data.

Comment: @Hiebs915 I have added a demo [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cfd2ee882c8d5f12ce038119a08b0ef1) link.

Comment: I just added two more columns of data that are used in the `WHERE` clause.  I don't think they will make a diff. but I'll need to use them on my end.

Comment: The section you posted works but when I incorporate with my existing `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses, I get two errors: "Column 'ConstructDate.EventDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" and, "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified".

The ORDER BY error is my fault, there are more well types than I listed in my original query.  After removing my ORDER BY clause and adding on cd.EventDate to the `GROUP BY` clause, your answer works.

Comment: It stands to reason you need to modify it if you're going to modify the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't verify the request without data. I would try subquery with "Grouping Set" operator in combination with "Case When" structure and then use "SUM" aggregate function.

```
With Cte As (Select YEAR(GetDate()) As [YEAR], YEAR(GetDate())-4 As [first]             
             Union All 
             Select [YEAR]-1 As [YEAR], [first]
             From cte
             Where [YEAR] > [first])
Select WellTypes, SUM([2021]), SUM([2020]), SUM([2019]), SUM([2018]), SUM([2017])
From
(Select
    COALESCE(w.WellType, 'Totals') As WellTypes,
    Case When cte.[YEAR] = YEAR(GetDate()) Then COUNT(DISTINCT(w.WellID)) End As [2021],
    Case When cte.[YEAR] = Year(GetDate())-1 Then COUNT(DISTINCT(w.WellID)) End As [2020],
    Case When cte.[YEAR] = Year(GetDate())-2 Then COUNT(DISTINCT(w.WellID)) End As [2019],
    Case When cte.[YEAR] = Year(GetDate())-3 Then COUNT(DISTINCT(w.WellID)) End As [2018],
    Case When cte.[YEAR] = Year(GetDate())-4 Then COUNT(DISTINCT(w.WellID)) End As [2017]
From Well w
    Inner Join Construct c ON c.WellKey = w.PKey
    Inner Join ConstructDate cd ON c.PKey = cd.ConstructKey
    Inner Join cte On (YEAR(cd.EventDate)=cte.[YEAR])
Where
    And cd.Event = 'LATERALSTATUS'
    And cd.Comment = 'PA'
Group by Grouping Sets ((cte.[YEAR], w.WellType), (cte.[YEAR]))) As T
Group by WellTypes
Order by
    Case WellTypes
        When 'OW' Then 1
        When 'GW' Then 2
        When 'D' Then 3
        When 'OWI' Then 4
        When 'WI' Then 5
    End Desc
```

Comment: This works except the first `And` underneath `Where` needs to be removed.